# MVP + Dagger2 + Kotlin: lateinit property presenter has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin, dagger-2, mvp, onitemclicklistener

I setup my project to MVP architecture. I was able to setup MVP for `MainActivity` and `ListAdapter`. Basically I have a list of images in `ListAdapter`, when item clicked, it will start `PhotoDetailActivity` which I've setup `Presenter` and `View` already.

ListAdapter.kt (Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/truongnmt/c0f1ecb36f39432151e78c557e0dea66))

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val photo = photos[position]
    holder.bind(photo)
    holder.itemLayout.setOnClickListener {
        listener.itemDetail(photo.id)
    }
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(photo.urls.regular)
            .into(holder.photo)
    Glide
            .with(context)
            .load(photo.user.profile_image.small)
            .into(holder.userAvatar)
}
```

PhotoDetailActivity.kt (Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/truongnmt/53a25147f17e40d165d0b4331f6bd87a))

```
lateinit var presenter: PhotoDetailContract.Presenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_detail)
    var photoId: String = intent.getStringExtra("photoId")

    injectDependency()
    presenter.attach(this)
    initView(photoId)
}
```

But it said that:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property presenter has not been initialized
```

My full code is [here](https://github.com/TranBaVinhSon/base_mvp_sample/tree/di)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dagger2 + Kotlin: lateinit property has not been initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554654/dagger2-kotlin-lateinit-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

declaring the member like this:

```
lateinit var presenter: PhotoDetailContract.Presenter
```

..inidicates that this reference will be initialized at some point after the constructor has run. however, you don't seem to have any code instrumented to do so. having glanced at your project, i think what you might have meant was for Dagger to inject that that instance. to do so, you need to add the `@Inject` annotation, like so:

```
@Inject lateinit var presenter: PhotoDetailContract.Presenter
```

Comment: Right, how silly I am, thanks a lot braaaaaaaaaaaaaa