# Dagger: lateinit property has not been initialized

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dependency-management, dagger

There already several QAs on this question, but for me they seem to talk about different things (Android's Kotlin + Dagger2, in most of the case) and not applying my specific case.

I'm learning Dagger by reading [this blog post](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/dagger-2-for-android-beginners-dagger-2-part-i-f2de5564ab25). Instead using the Java code from that blog, I'm trying to use Kotlin.

So, the `House.kt` as interface:

```
interface House {
    fun prepareForWar()
    fun reportForWar()
}
```

The as-is `BoltonsDagger.kt`:

```
class BoltonsDagger @Inject constructor(): House {
    override fun reportForWar() {
        println("${this.javaClass.simpleName} reporting..")
    }

    override fun prepareForWar() {
        println("${this.javaClass.simpleName} prepared for war")
    }
}
```

The as-is `StarksDagger.kt`:

```
class StarksDagger @Inject constructor(): House {
    override fun prepareForWar() {
        println("${this.javaClass.simpleName} prepared for war")
    }

    override fun reportForWar() {
        println("${this.javaClass.simpleName} reporting..")
    }
}
```

Finally the `WarDagger.kt` with `main` function:

```
class WarDagger @Inject constructor() {
    @Inject lateinit var starks: StarksDagger
    @Inject lateinit var boltons:BoltonsDagger

    fun prepare() {
        starks.prepareForWar()
        boltons.prepareForWar()
    }

    fun report() {
        starks.reportForWar()
        boltons.reportForWar()
    }
}

fun main() {
    val war = WarDagger()
    war.prepare()
    war.report()
}
```

With the error: `Exception in thread "main" kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property starks has not been initialized`.

Comment: Have you performed DI somewhere? Also please check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554654/dagger2-kotlin-lateinit-property-has-not-been-initialized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, change the `WarDagger` to following:

```
class WarDagger @Inject constructor(
    private val starks: StarksDagger,
    private val boltons: BoltonsDagger
) {
    ...
}
```

With this you are making Dagger aware as to how an instance of `WarDagger` should be created. There is no need to annotate constructor fields with `@Inject`.

I cannot locate dagger component in the question, so let's create one:

```
@Component
interface WarComponent {
    fun provideWarDagger(): WarDagger
}
```

We are making an instance of `WarDagger` accessible through the component, so that clients can get an instance of it.

Now, inside `main` instead of manually creating an instance of `WarDagger` you should be retrieving it from the dagger component, because that's the whole reason that you are using a DI framework, isn't it? Clients should not be aware how dependencies are being created:

```
fun main() {
    val component = DaggerWarComponent.create()
    val war = component.provideWarDagger()
    war.prepare()
    war.report()
}
```